# How to show progress bar with percentage using volley?

Tags: android, android-volley, android-progressbar

In my application, I am uploading images and text responses to my server. I want to show a progress dialog with percentage while uploading.
Here is my code ,
code to call volley function :

```
//look at send data to server 

// Send to server .calling my volley function

    new NetworkController(context).sendAuditData(row, URL_Config.SAVE_AUDIT);
```

My volley to code to send data to server,

```
public void sendAuditData(final HashMap<String,String> audit_data,final String url)
    {

//        HttpsTrustManager.allowAllSSL();
        createProgressDialog();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        String val[] = response.split(",");
                        if(val[0].equalsIgnoreCase("success")){
                            Toast.makeText(context,"Data submitted successly",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            CheckSuiteDAOI dao = new CheckSuiteDAO(context);
                            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                            cv.put("sync_status","true");
                            dao.update_data(cv,"date_time=?",new String[] {val[1]},"CONTAINER_MASTER");

                            successDialog(audit_data);

                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        dismisProgressDialog();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){

                return audit_data;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        int socketTimeout         = 5000;//7seconds - change to what you want
        RetryPolicy policy        = new DefaultRetryPolicy(socketTimeout, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT);
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(policy);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to show a progress dialog -- Possible
>
> With percentage while upload -- Not Possible. This is some thing multipart upload by chunks of data. Api support also required.
>
> Think 10 mb file your uploading and you set up 5 threads which uploading 2 mb. So uploading 2 threads success happens 40% completed. It works like that.

Comment: then how to achieve it ?

Comment: are you doing by Multi-part form data?
 1> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790427/show-progress-value-for-volley-file-download
2> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076978/how-to-show-progress-bar-while-uploading-with-percentage